# HTML form to Excel Web to Email template filled

Tags: javascript, excel, forms, outlook, power-automate

I have made it before using HTML form, google sheets and Gmail, but I don't know if it is possible to do it with excel.

I need my HTML form responses to be saved in a row on excel web, then there are some formulas that will calculate depending on the form data , the formulas are on another tab.

Whenever a form is received on the HTML form and saved to Excel, excel should automatically run a script that will get the values from those formulas and paste the values on the same row as the received form data.

The row then will be complete and an html email template with all data will be sent to the email saved on the row.

Is it possible to do it using excel web? To trigger a macro on form receipt

Is there another patch to achieve it ?

If anyone knows it please let me know.